# JQuery - On Click Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that I'm trying to attach an event handler to. I've tried two different ways but neither seems to work. Is there something missing?

```
//on ready
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //this triggers when page loads, why?
    //$("#button").on('click', alert("clicked"));   

    //this doesn't work, why?
    $("#button").on('click', function() {
        alert("clicked");
    });

});
```

Here's a JsFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/LrWvE/

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` in your console

Comment: The first one "triggers" when page load because your second argument is not a function, but instead a call to the method `alert` and it's return value is going to be used as the second argument.

Comment: `$("#button").on('click', alert("clicked")); ` works because the `alert(...)` is evaluated before the `.on(...)` is evaluated so the alert is displayed then the error is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on ()` is added in jquery  1.7+. use `.live()` for jq libraries <1.7 or upgrade library to version 1.7+.

**[Demo using .on](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/LrWvE/1)**

**[Demo using .live](http://jsfiddle.net/Pey4E/)**